# tf.where() takes extra time on first use for every new tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, tensorflow

**Edit:** Wanted to clarify that my machine >I use is an Nvidia Xavier AGX (the program is also meant to be run on an NX), and that might be a cause of these slow preformance times, I want to know if there is a faster option.

I'm writing code which is supposed to read an image, use it to get an inference from a segmentation model, then color the output and display(/save) it as a rgb image.

The output of my model is a tensor with a shape of (256, 352, 7) where 7 is for the number of classes and each value corresponds to its confidence of that object class.

I need all of this to run in real-time of about 50ms but anything less is great. my model runs an inference in 17ms but my problem comes later when I run tf commands.

I tried converting the tensor to a numpy array in order to color it and to use cv2 operations easier, but the conversion function takes ~80ms.

Instead, I tried creating a new numpy array and I fill it with the right rgb color (which is predetermined) for each class for each pixel by using the `tf.where()` command.

This is my code:
`

```
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(input, dtype=tf.uint8)

output_model = model(tensor)
output = tf.argmax(output_model[0], axis=-1)
mask = np.zeros((HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(len(colors)):
    indices = tf.where(tf.equal(output, i))
    mask[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]] = colors[i][::-1]
```

`

Now when i run this for a certain tensor, the first time it run the `tf.where()` function with a tensor of (256, 352), it takes ~80ms and for the 6 times after the it takes ~3-5ms, then for every new tensor it takes the same 80ms for the first call, eventhough they are the exact same shape and type.

I read that its because tensorflow is building the right structures for the tensor at the first time then reuses it every other time, but it seems it resets for every new tensor.

My question is: is the a way to introduce to tensorflow the shape and type of the tensor i'm about to input, as they are all the same size and type and therfore lead to me getting a runtime of ~4ms each time I call `tf.where()`.

I looked into `tf,function`s but I couldnt make it work quicker:

`

```
@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[HEIGHT, WIDTH], dtype=tf.int64), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64),))
def tfwhere(tensor, value):
    return tf.where(tf.equal(tensor, value))
```

`

I also tried using a "dummy tensor" first with the same shape but got the same kind of results.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the loop completely and implement a `vectorized` implementation.

```
tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.one_hot(output, n_classes), colors[None, None,...]))
```

Consider this example,

```
HEIGHT, WIDTH = 32, 32
n_classes = 7

output = np.random.randint(0, 8,size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
#an random output with 0-7 as values.

mask = np.zeros((HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
colors = np.ones((n_classes,3)) *np.arange(n_classes)[..., None]
#here the color is chosen such that its RGB values are class_ids, just for debugging purposes
#color[3] = (3,3,3) and so on.
```

Here the `one_hot` adds zeros to other classes except for the selected one, and `matmul` with the colors will just get that particular value selected from `colors` matrix.

```
colored_out  = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.one_hot(output, n_classes), colors[None, None,...]))

Checking output for a random index,
colored_out[7][7].numpy(), output[7][7]
 #array([3., 3., 3.],  array([3]
```

Comment: my output is a 2D array with a shape of [256, 352, 8], does this still apply?

Comment: yes. you just need to change the params mentioned in the example. I put a toy example, so that you can understand and verify what's happening.

Comment: Ok, but the output is still a tensor, which takes my machine (Nvidia Xavier AGX) ~80ms to preform the conversion to numpy using .numpy()...

Comment: the above is a tensor operation, you perform on the GPU itself. Don't do numpy() conversion.

Comment: I may not have clarified it as best I could in the post, but I need for the end result to be an image, I chose using numpy as i can easily save it using opencv. The conversion time to png needs to be as minimal as possible... hopefully under 50ms

Comment: the end result is the RGB image, where each class id in the output is replaced by an RGB value to form an image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250351/discussion-between-v-m-and-aidan-abramson).